# How to execute more than one lambda in different microservices listening for the cognito PreSignUp event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, amazon-cognito-triggers

Until recently I had a lambda in a microservice that triggered with the cognito PreSignUp event. Now I need to run another one in another microservice, but since I put it in, only one really runs. What do I have to do to be able to execute both, even more lambdas, with the same trigger event?

Comment: Create a lambda that invokes the other lambda(s) and set Cognito to call the invoker lambda. Make sure not to take long than 5 seconds or Cognito will timeout and try the call again.

Comment: @hvaughan3 thank you very much for the reply. I understand that it is not a good pattern to call lambdas from other lambdas unless it is very necessary, so I would like to know other ways that exist.

Comment: You have a few alternatives but they all ultimately result in one lambda calling many others, each just has different middle-man between them. You could have you Cognito trigger lambda make multiple API calls to each of your micro-service endpoints or you could have each micro-service lambda subscribed to an SNS topic and the Cognito trigger lambda would send a message to said topic to trigger subscribers. I am sure there are other methods which add some resiliency and standardization between a single lambda triggering multiple other lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything below, make sure not to take longer than 5 seconds or Cognito will timeout and try the call again up to 3 times.

1. Have a Cognito trigger lambda calling multiple other child lambdas, using `invoke()`

```js
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: 'us-east-1', apiVersion: '2015-03-31'})

await Promise.all([
  lambda.invoke({
      FunctionName: 'ChildLambda1',
      InvocationType: 'Event',
      LogType: 'None',
      Payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(<DATA HERE>))
    }).promise(),
  lambda.invoke({
      FunctionName: 'ChildLambda2',
      InvocationType: 'Event',
      LogType: 'None',
      Payload: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(<DATA HERE>))
    }).promise()
])
```

2. Set a trigger lambda that simply makes API calls to each of the micro-service endpoints that need to be triggered
3. Have each child lambda subscribe to an SNS topic and have the Cognito trigger lambda send a message to said topic ([AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html))

```js
// SNS subscriptions to "Cognito_PreSignUp" topic are configured in AWS console

// Send message from Cognito trigger lambda
const sns = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'})

await sns.publish({
  Message: JSON.stringify(<DATA HERE>),
  TopicArn: 'Cognito_PreSignUp'
}).promise()
```